# Android permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL

Tags: android, permissions

I have a large app in android.

From time to time the application crashes with an error not clear. I do not know exactly when and why this happens.

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks
to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires 
android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
```

Any help?

Comment: @offset Did you ever get this to work?

Comment: @user1147688 I don't remember...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for
>   user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires 
>   android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL

Add this `android:protectionLevel="signature"` in your manifest .

For more details, you can check [**`Permission-Element`**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html)

**Like:**

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
```

Comment: No, unfortunately the bug happened again... Where to add this line?

Comment: android:protectionLevel is a valid attribute for <permission>. You have it on <manifest> and on <application> From @Commonsware Sir

Comment: Like that? `<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />`

Comment: No, The bug keeps happening

Comment: <permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

Comment: signature is not something you can get just by adding it. It's SIGNATURED by OEM

Comment: i keep reading about the CAUSE of the problem, but no solution.  What is the solution?

Comment: Android Studio confirms what @Felix.D just said, "Permissions with the protection level signature, privileged or signatureOrSystem are only granted to system apps. If an app is a regular non-system app, it will never be able to use these permissions."

Comment: For some reason I have this exception on 
Xiaomi Mi A1 with what seems to be some custom rom (LineageSettings class, so probably LineageOs) . Any idea why?

Answer (score 20):

To summarize from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22064389/1147688) answer, and looking at the sources of [UserHandle.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/os/UserHandle.java) we see the meaning of the *framework* user id's.

```
# | @UserIdInt            | Value  | Status     | Description |
# | --------------------- | ------ | ---------- | ------------| 
# | USER_OWNER            | 0      | deprecated | "owner" user of the device
# | USER_SYSTEM           | 0      | ok         | "system" user of the device
# | USER_ALL              | -1     | ok         | ALL users on the device
  | USER_CURRENT          | -2     | ok         | the currently active user
# | USER_CURRENT_OR_SELF  | -3     | ok         | id from which we would like to send to the current user
# | USER_NULL             | -10000 | ok         | An undefined user id
```

---

Then to understand what `android:protectionLevel="signature"` means, you'll have to read the page about [permission-element](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html). Which is summarized in the table:

[image]

So what you need to do in your `AndroidManifest.xml` depend a lot on what API's you need to support, as higher > 23 API's also require a `android:permissionGroup=` [definition](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#perm-groups), for non-normal ("dangerous") permissions...

**Also good to know** (by @CommonsWare)

To be able to hold `INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS`, your app has to be **signed** by the firmware's signing key **or** it has to be installed on the system partition.

To be able to hold `INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL`, your app has to be signed by the firmware's signing key.

Comment: i keep reading about the CAUSE of the problem, but not the SOLUTION.  What is the solution?

Comment: @sudocoder The solution is (as already shown in the 2 sentences above) to sign your app with the device manufacturers (or OS providers) OEM key! Please post a new SO question if this is not enough, or perhaps look at the [Android specific SE](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: fair, those two sentences make a solution.  but how is this solution scalable?  eg: if i sign this with a Samsung key, wouldn't a Huawei user who downloaded my app have this same problem?

Comment: when I try to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" android:protectionLevel="signature" />` I get "Permissions with the protection level signature, privileged or signatureOrSystem are only granted to system apps. If an app is a regular non-system app, it will never be able to use these permissions."

Comment: Is there a way to detect whether the app is running on the real user's account, and not a secondary?

Answer (score 3):

Same issue i was getting when i use **billingProcessor.subscribe()** or **billingProcessor.purchase()** with two parameter as Activity and **product_id** of product. There was i pass the value of **product_id is empty**.

Please once make sure that you are passing value in the product_id is not empty.

Answer (score 3):

One of the possible solutions is to disable auto-fill, but it works only on Android Oreo. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45731372/disabling-android-o-auto-fill-service-for-an-application?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Simply add this code to your app :

```
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        window.decorView.importantForAutofill = 
        View.IMPORTANT_FOR_AUTOFILL_NO_EXCLUDE_DESCENDANTS;
    }
```

And rename getUserId() method if you have it.

Comment: wtf, rename getUserId() method if you have it. this line save me! why!? thanks you

Comment: Do you know why getUserId() causes this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Just ran into it after updating the OS on the device.

A hard restart solved it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a very strange error ... I got this one after I switched from Java to Kotlin or maybe from any Android Studio update. I started to comment elements one by one from both XML and .kt files till I found that the error had nothing to do with any userId (which was mentioned in the error), not any Retrofit call either, the error was caused by one Spinner element in XML, nothing about it in .kt file when I loaded the elements, just this:

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/number_people_sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text" />
```

So I deleted it and things went good again. I'm thinking that the problem was caused by some spacing of elements (because that spinner was in a Fragment in a Tabbed Activity) and I see in the long lines of error something about spacing and child measures.

Have in mind just to check any possible small thing in the error file, the error could be from anything ...

Answer (score 0):

I've been faced with the same issue "**android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL**" when i upgraded the OS version of my android device. i tried to **clean and rebuild project** and the issues has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error right after updating phone OS to Android 9. Nothing but resetting (restarting) phone and restarting Android Studio worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I was using a `notificationChannel`. I had created it using a `applicationContext` but in other place I was trying to get it from context of a service by `NotificationManager.getNotificationChannel()`. So probably using the same context in different places for example `applicationContext` can fix this problem.

Answer (score -2):

i resolved this issue by luck . I was using a singleton fragment instance which caused this issue. When i replaced the `fragment.getInstance()` call with `new fragment()` it worked like a charm. fragments shouldnt be used as singletons and should be brought back (if required) with the saved state.

Comment: this is likely not the root cause experienced by OP