# AudioManager.setMode() SecurityException on Huawei Android 4

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-audiomanager

I have a crash that is only happening on Huawei devices..

It crashed when the app is trying to set audio mode

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
```

here is the crash log:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.example.android.services.CallService: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2609)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:139)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1290)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1472)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1426)
       at android.media.IAudioService$Stub$Proxy.setMode(IAudioService.java:1398)
       at android.media.AudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.java:1490)
       at com.example.android.sipsdk.SipMediaManager.initialize(SipMediaManager.java:36)
       at com.example.android.services.SipWrapper.init(SipWrapper.java:64)
       at com.example.android.services.CallService.onCreate(CallService.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2599)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:139)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1290)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Comment: I think this link will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28134128/android-permission-interact-across-users-full