# Getting ERROR like requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL

Tags: android

Getting that error when I am doing Inter app communication with custom Intent using sendBroadcast. I have tried all the possible ways but unable to resolve this. Please help me to find the solution.

Comment: Did u try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28134128/android-permission-interact-across-users-full

Comment: tried that but still I am getting the same error

Comment: Can u post ur manifest

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.vsadhana.omni">

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.vsadhana.omni"
        android:label="omni" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.vsadhana.omni" />

Answer (score 1):

you could try to add this to your Manifest

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
```

If you would like to learn more about permissions you could click [Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html).
I hope that this works for you!

Comment: I have added that but still I am getting the same error

Comment: Have you cleaned your project? Sometimes, this can solve your problem.