# Start Activity with TextInputLayout throw SecurityException

Tags: android, android-securityexception, android-autofill-manager

When trying to Start Activity With TextInputLayout it throw SecurityException.
I check if I remove All TextInputLayout it works just fine.
I look every where there was a hint about AutoFill framework cause this but I can't found any solution for it.
Error Log:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: null asks to run as user 3 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL or android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2005)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1951)
    at android.view.autofill.IAutoFillManager$Stub$Proxy.addClient(IAutoFillManager.java:358)
    at android.view.autofill.AutofillManager.ensureServiceClientAddedIfNeededLocked(AutofillManager.java:1113)
    at android.view.autofill.AutofillManager.notifyViewExited(AutofillManager.java:633)
    at android.view.View.notifyEnterOrExitForAutoFillIfNeeded(View.java:6994)
    at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:17522)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3344)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3344)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3344)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3344)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3344)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3344)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3344)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3344)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3344)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3344)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1672)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1396)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6773)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:974)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:786)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:721)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:960)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6501)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: Did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28134128/android-permission-interact-across-users-full)?

Comment: try disabling autofill with `android:importantForAutofill:noExcludeDescendants`

Comment: @Piyush Yes. not working.

Comment: @VivekMishra You are a life savior man. It's working. Many Thanks

Comment: @VivekMishra There is New problem when I Highlight all text autofill throw exception again :|

Comment: With new problem ask new question with all the details

Comment: Any one has any Idea what to do ?!