# How to give permission INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS to normal apps and handle this situation ? why this permission required?

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

App works well in all version of android device at installation time (First time) but when I open next time on **Android P**,it throws following exception

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.merojob.merojobapp/com.merojob.merojobapp.SplashScreenActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Call from user 0 as user 361911 without permission INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS or INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL not allowed.
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
   at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

and i searched over internet ,I found this question  [Android permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28134128/android-permission-interact-across-users-full).
I put **permission** in manifest as

```
 <permission
    android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

But this solution doesn't work in my case . The crash is happening again and again. I think it's because of multiUser problem . I also searched about that and found this link 
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/67038/can-somebody-explain-how-multi-user-is-implemented-in-android-4-4/67040#67040

Is there any idea how to handle this problem ?

here is my  manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="***************">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<permission
    android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<application
    android:name=".MeroJobApp"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppThemeJobSeeker">
    <meta-data
        android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
        android:value="*****************************" />

    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
        android:allowTaskReparenting="true"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:showForAllUsers="true"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat" />

    <activity
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:showForAllUsers="true"
        android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:showForAllUsers="true"
        android:name=".activity.LoginActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:showForAllUsers="true"
        android:name=".activity.TutorialActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />


    <receiver
        android:name=".utils.ConnectivityReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".Services.CustomFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name=".Services.CustomFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
        android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />

</application>
```

and app level build.gradle file is here

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {

compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "************"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 22
    versionName "2.9.1"

testInstrumentationRunner"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        //  buildConfigField 'String', "APP_KEY", APP_KEY
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),'proguard-rules.pro'
        resValue("bool", "FIREBASE_CRASH_ENABLED", "true")
    }

    debug {
        resValue("bool", "FIREBASE_CRASH_ENABLED", "false")
    }

}
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path 'src/CMakeLists.txt'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
/*
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
*/
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
// compile 'com.android.support:exifinterface:27.0.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'

implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
implementation 'com.orhanobut:hawk:2.0.1'
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
implementation 'com.github.xiprox:ErrorView:v2.2.0.1'
implementation 'com.github.ragunathjawahar:android-saripaar:android-saripaar-2.0.3'
implementation 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2@aar'
implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.5.1'
implementation 'org.ocpsoft.prettytime:prettytime:4.0.1.Final'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.29.0'

implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'

//  implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.0.0'
implementation 'com.splitwise:tokenautocomplete:2.0.8@aar'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
///implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.1'
}

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
    def requested = details.requested
    if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
        if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
            details.useVersion '26.0.1'
        }
    }
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got answer !

As android 28 has some restrictions , All developers should review these changes and modify their apps to support them properly, where applicable to the app.

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-all

Here are my some changes in code

1. Android 9 has new features like rotation.It might crash when you set it to portrait mode constantly in manifest.It is better to request rotation from code. so I remove **android:screenOrientation="portrait"**
   from **manifest.xml**
2. Another problem in my code is static registration of broadcast

   ```
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
   </intent-filter>
   ```

   Action **android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE** is deprecated in android P. so I register it dynamically in BaseActivity.java as

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onResume() {
   super.onResume();
   registerReceiver(connectReceiver, newIntentFilter("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"));
      }
   ```
3. I update all library in **build.gradle** and remove unnecessary implementations

As conclusion ,

- please , first read full documentation of android behaviour changes
- make necessary changes (Orientation, Broadcast,Backgroud service etc) , as they are restricted

Thank you !

**UPDATE**

Hey Guys , Quickly search for method **getUserId()** , if you have this method in your application level class or Activity , just rename this method name .