# Android 9 (API 28) activity crashes on start (setContentView)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-9.0-pie

The issue started when updating my phone from Android 8 to 9.
The app was working perfectly before.

I tried to replicate this in some other app I am working on, by including the same dependencies/configuration, but I am unable to replicate the behavior. It always crashes at the setContentView, even for a simple activity and simple layout.

I did my research and came to the conclusion that `INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL` permission is not the real cause of the issue.

This crash actually happens in all app activities, but the TestActivity is the simplest one. Tested on Samsung S9+ running API 28 and Pixel Emulator running Android 9, API 28.

**EDIT**: This seems to happen when I put the android:name="...." attribute to the manifest definition. Since I really need the application class, I'm still in search of a solution to make this work.

---

The activity (simplified to have the minimum code needed for a crash):

> ```
> package com.marhat.albatros
>
> import android.os.Bundle import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
>
> class TestActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
>     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
>         setContentView(R.layout.activity_test)
>     }
> }
> ```

---

Layout:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>                                                      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>                                                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                                                      android:layout_height="match_parent"
>                                                      tools:context=".TestActivity">
>
> </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
> ```

---

This is the output:

> ```
> 2019-02-08 11:54:19.088 20298-20298/com.marhat.albatros E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>     Process: com.marhat.albatros, PID: 20298
>     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.marhat.albatros/com.marhat.albatros.TestActivity}:
> ```
>
> java.lang.SecurityException: Call from user 0 as user 1 without
>   permission INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS or INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL not
>   allowed.
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
>               at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
>               at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
>               at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>            Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Call from user 0 as user 1 without permission INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS or
>   INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL not allowed.
>               at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1942)
>               at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1910)
>               at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1860)
>               at android.view.accessibility.IAccessibilityManager$Stub$Proxy.addClient(IAccessibilityManager.java:295)
>               at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager.tryConnectToServiceLocked(AccessibilityManager.java:1125)
>               at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager.(AccessibilityManager.java:358)
>               at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager.getInstance(AccessibilityManager.java:336)
>               at android.view.View.setFlags(View.java:14008)
>               at android.view.View.(View.java:5565)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:659)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:655)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:651)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:647)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.(FrameLayout.java:78)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.(DecorView.java:255)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.generateDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2310)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2662)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:2071)
>               at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:575)
>               at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
>               at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
>               at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>               at com.marhat.albatros.TestActivity.onCreate(TestActivity.kt:9)
>               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
>               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
>               at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
>               at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
>               at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>               at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
>            Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
>               at com.android.server.accessibility.AccessibilityManagerService$SecurityPolicy.resolveCallingUserIdEnforcingPermissionsLocked(AccessibilityManagerService.java:3522)
>               at com.android.server.accessibility.AccessibilityManagerService.addClient(AccessibilityManagerService.java:487)
>               at android.view.accessibility.IAccessibilityManager$Stub.onTransact(IAccessibilityManager.java:82)
>               at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:731)

---

Manifest:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>           package="com.marhat.albatros">
>
>     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
>     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
>     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
>     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
>     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
>
>     <uses-feature
>             android:name="android.hardware.usb.host"
>             android:required="true"/>
>     <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"/>
>
>     <application
>             android:name=".AlbatrossApplication"
>             android:allowBackup="true"
>             android:icon="@mipmap/ic_icon_main"
>             android:label="@string/app_name"
>             android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_icon_main_round"
>             android:supportsRtl="true"
>             android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
>         <activity
>                 android:name=".TestActivity"
>                 android:label="@string/title_activity_test"
>                 android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
>             <intent-filter>
>                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
>
>                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
>             </intent-filter>
>         </activity>
>         <activity
>                 android:name=".TasksActivity"
>                 android:label="@string/title_activity_tasks"
>                 android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
>
>         <meta-data
>                 android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
>                 android:value="xxx"/>
>
>         <activity
>                 android:name=".MainActivity"
>                 android:label="@string/app_name">
>             <intent-filter>
>                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
>
>                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
>             </intent-filter>
>         </activity>
>
>         <service
>                 android:name=".UsbService"
>                 android:enabled="true"/>
>
>         <activity android:name=".FPViewActivity"/>
>         <activity
>                 android:name=".SplashActivity"
>                 android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Launcher">
>             <intent-filter>
>                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
>
>                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
>             </intent-filter>
>         </activity>
>         <activity
>                 android:name=".TaskViewActivity"
>                 android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
>             <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
>                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
>
>                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
>                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
>
>                 <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
>                 <data android:scheme="file"/>
>                 <data android:scheme="content"/>
>                 <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.xfd"/>
>                 <data android:host="*"/>
>             </intent-filter>
>         </activity>
>         <activity
>                 android:name=".SettingsActivity"
>                 android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"/>
>     </application>
>
> </manifest>
> ```

---

Project gradle file:

> ```
> // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
>
> buildscript {
>     ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.21'
>     repositories {
>         google()
>         jcenter()
>         maven {
>             url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
>         }
>     }
>     dependencies {
>         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
>         classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
>         classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
>         classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'
>     } }
>
> allprojects {
>     repositories {
>         google()
>         jcenter()
>         maven {
>             url 'https://maven.google.com/'
>         }
>
>         maven {
>             url "https://jitpack.io"
>         }
>     } }
>
> task clean(type: Delete) {
>     delete rootProject.buildDir }
> ```

---

The app / gradle file:

> ```
> apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
> apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
> apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
> apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
> apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
>
> android {
>     compileSdkVersion 28
>     defaultConfig {
>         applicationId "com.marhat.albatros"
>         minSdkVersion 18
>         targetSdkVersion 28
>         multiDexEnabled true
>         versionCode 1
>         versionName "1.0"
>         testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
>         // vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
>     }
>     buildTypes {
>         release {
>             minifyEnabled true
>             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
>         }
>     }
>     compileOptions {
>         sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
>         targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
>     }
>
>     dataBinding {
>         enabled = true
>     }
> }
>
> dependencies {
>     implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'], dir: 'libs')
>     implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
>     implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
>     implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
>     implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28'
>     implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha3'
>     implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
>     implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
>     implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.1'
>     implementation 'com.github.QuadFlask:colorpicker:0.0.13'
>     testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
>     androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
>     androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
>     implementation 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0'
>     implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
>     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
>     implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.8'
>     implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.0.1'
>     implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.0.1'
>     implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
>     implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
>     def room_version = "2.1.0-alpha04"
>     implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
>     kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
>     testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"
>     def lifecycle_version = "2.0.0"
>     implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
>     kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"
>     implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle_version"
>     implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-reactivestreams:$lifecycle_version"
>     testImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$lifecycle_version"
>     implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.0'
>     implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
>
>     implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
>     implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
>     implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.3.0'
>     implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'
>
> }
>
> apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
> ```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android permission.INTERACT\_ACROSS\_USERS\_FULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28134128/android-permission-interact-across-users-full)

Comment: there are duplicate dependencies, strange version numbers, etc. it's hard to believe that this `build.gradle` ever built properly - even when not overriding `.getUserId()`... either use `com.android.support` - or use `androidx`; not both.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with the application class implementing a method called getUserId.
After renaming the method everything started to work on Android 9 again.

Answer (score 0):

i finally found the solution it's work.... charm
1) -> Copy Parse to you Manifest

```
<!--Support Android Pie 9-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

2) -> Find and replace all getUserId Occurrence
for Mac user:use Cmd+Shift+R 
Example on MAC

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLtWR.png