# Cannot run project in Android Studio 3.4.1 on Samsung Devices

Tags: java, android, android-studio, exception, build

I am unable to run a project on my Samsung device from Android Studio 3.4.1. Studio is giving me the following error message in a dialog box

```
Installation failed with message 'cmd package install-create -r -t -S 1686629' returns error 'Unknown failure: Security exception: Permission Denial: runInstallCreate from pm command asks to run as user -1 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: runInstallCreate from pm command asks to run as user -1 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
at com.android.server.am.UserController.handleIncomingUser(UserController.java:1827)
at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:25069)
at android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:4848)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.translateUserId(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:2402)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.doCreateSession(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:2408)
```

I tried the fix mentioned in the message, ie adding a permission in manifest file, but still the error is not going away while running.

Please note, the project is building without errors.

How do I fix this?

My System details

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

Android Studio Details

Android Studio 3.4.1
Build #AI-183.6156.11.34.5522156, built on May 1, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b16-5323222 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.15.0-52-generic

Comment: for me it looks like a problem with the phone itself. Have you tried other devices?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28134128/android-permission-interact-across-users-full

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko, on other devices it is running

Comment: then it is obviously problem with the device

Comment: In another system, I am able to run the app on that same device

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue after upgrading a Galaxy Tab Active 2 to Android Pie (9.0).

The solution that worked for me:

1. Uninstall the App
2. Disable and Re-Enable Developer Options.
3. Re-Enable USB Debugging (it didn't work after that step just yet)
4. Reboot the tablet

Others reported success by adding the the INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL permission into the manifest.

If you're still stuck, other solutions steps regarding the same error message are available here:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/android-permission-interact_across_users_full.536280/

Comment: I had the same problem on the same device. In my case I had to reboot the tablet.